# Correctly setting my DataContext in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I know there are similar questions but I am getting this wrong.

I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StudentList x:Key="StudentList" />
    <local:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter" />
    <local:StudentAssignmentToStudentAssignmentLookup x:Key="LookupHistoryConvertor" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsStudentList" Source="{StaticResource StudentList}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:OCLMEditorModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Futher down in my markup I have a `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Name="gridStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsStudentList}}"
          Margin="2"
          Height="250"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
```

But I don't think it is right anymore. My OCLMEditorModel object has a public **property** called `StudentList`. If I am understanding this right, at the moment my window is associated with an instance of `OCLMEditorModel`. But the subsequent DataGrid is associated with a **distinct** instance of the CollectionViewSource.

So I am getting myself confused. Thanks for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying changing your

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsStudentList" Source="{StaticResource StudentList}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
```

to

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsStudentList" Source="{Binding StudentList}" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter"/>
```

You're correct that your DataContext is set initially to an instance of `OCLMEditorModel` when the window is instantiated. That should mean that your CollectionViewSource resource should be able to grab the `StudentList` property from the Window's DataContext through a direct binding.

Yes, what you're doing in your xaml is binding your DataGrid's ItemsSource to a distinct instance of the CollectionViewSource. *However*, you're also binding that `CollectionViewSource` instance to a **distinct** instance of a `StudentList` defined in your Window.Resources (    `<local:StudentList x:Key="StudentList" />`
), which I don't think is what you want. The change I suggested above will make your `CollectionViewSource` bind to the `OCLMEditorModel`'s StudentList property instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: If I do this it tells me that StudentList is not supported in the WPF.

Comment: I had forgotten Binding word. But now my grid shows no data.

Comment: Sorted. I forgot I had renamed my property to Students.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle definitely my least favorite thing about WPF! :D

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just bind to the `StudentList` property, like

```
<DataGrid Name="gridStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentList}" ... />
```

Comment: He's likely using a collectionviewsource because he wants to sort. Directly binding to the property won't do

Comment: @Rowbear I am using the cvs because of Filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You directly define your collectionviewsource in the viewmodel and bind collectionviewsource to DataGrid ItemSource

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<student> StudentList { get; set; }

    public ICollectionView StudentView { get; set; }

    public StudentViewModel()
    {
        StudentList= new ObservableCollection<student>();
        StudentView = new CollectionView(StudentList);
        StudentView.Filter = Filter;
        StudentView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name",ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }

    private bool Filter(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

<DataGrid Name="gridStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding StudentView}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks. I have it working based on the other answer. I guess yours in code behind as opposed to in XAML. But both ends with the same result.

Comment: As a side note, I called my class `OCLMEditorModel` but it sounds like I should have called it `OCLMEditorViewModel`? And my source `XML` file would be considered the `Model` object?

Comment: Note:you defined your collectionviewsource in xaml and its filter in code behind in xaml.cs, that is violation of mvvm.

Comment: Sorry? In my code in the question the filter handler is specified in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `DataContext` to the following way...

```
 <Window.Resources>
            <local:OCLMEditorModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
        </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}" Name="gridStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsStudentList}}"
              Margin="2"
              Height="250"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about the cvs? We need that bound to the OCLMEditor  Student list property. Wouldn't this need to change too?